# CodeEffects demo project giving exception: Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I have downloaded the code effects demo ASP.Net project for VS2013 to test its business rules on one of my own dll. I updated the .net framework from 4.5 to 4.5.1 because my assembly was built in 4.5.1.
But unfortunately when I set the SourceAssembly and SourceType properties to point my dll and class, I get following exception

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I think I missed some dependencies. Adding them to the project resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.